# Sticky Footer Moves Out Of Place when Text and Form are Floated - BootStrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I am trying to float Text to the Left and Form to the right so they are side by side. However upon doing so, the footer moves out of place and both items dont get aligned properly

I am trying to get the Text and Form side by side, and when below the Max Width(@media) the Text should be on TOP and form BELOW

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Soni's Computer Repair</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

            .footer {
                position:relative;
                bottom:0;
                margin:auto;
            }

            body {
                font-family:"Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-weight:300;
                font-size: 12px;
                color:#777;
            }

            #contact input[type="text"], #contact input[type="email"], #contact input[type="tel"], #contact input[type="url"], #contact textarea, #contact button[type="submit"] { font:400 12px/16px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

            #contact {
                background:#F9F9F9;
                padding:25px;
                margin:50px 0;
            }

            #contact h3 {
                color: #F96;
                display: block;
                font-size: 30px;
                font-weight: 400;
            }

            #contact h4 {
                margin:5px 0 15px;
                display:block;
                font-size:13px;
            }

            fieldset {
                border: medium none !important;
                margin: 0 0 10px;
                min-width: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #contact input[type="text"], #contact input[type="email"], #contact input[type="tel"], #contact input[type="url"], #contact textarea {
                width:100%;
                border:1px solid #CCC;
                background:#FFF;
                margin:0 0 5px;
                padding:10px;
            }

            #contact input[type="text"]:hover, #contact input[type="email"]:hover, #contact input[type="tel"]:hover, #contact input[type="url"]:hover, #contact textarea:hover {
                -webkit-transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
                transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
                border:1px solid #AAA;
            }

            #contact textarea {
                height:100px;
                max-width:100%;
              resize:none;
            }

            #contact button[type="submit"] {
                cursor:pointer;
                width:100%;
                border:none;
                background:#0CF;
                color:#FFF;
                margin:0 0 5px;
                padding:10px;
                font-size:15px;
            }

            #contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
                background:#09C;
                -webkit-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
                transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
            }

            #contact button[type="submit"]:active { box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

            #contact input:focus, #contact textarea:focus {
                outline:0;
                border:1px solid #999;
            }
            ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
             color:#888;
            }
            :-moz-placeholder {
             color:#888;
            }
            ::-moz-placeholder {
             color:#888;
            }
            :-ms-input-placeholder {
             color:#888;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width:700px) {
                .mainInfo {
                text-align: center;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            .form {
                max-width: 400px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;

            }

            .contactInfo {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                text-align: center;
                border:1px solid red;
                max-width: 80%;

            }
            }


        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <center>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Final.png"/></a>
                    </center>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mainInfo">
            <div class="contactInfo">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <p>Mobile: 07588418134</p>
            <p>Mobile: 07572601345</p>
            <p>Email: info@SonisRepair.com</p>
            <p><b>Alternatively, you can email us using the Contact Form below, and we will get back to you within 24 Hours</b></p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="form">  
                <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
                    <h3>Get in Touch:</h3>
                    <h4>We aim to reply within 24 hours!</h4>
                    <fieldset>
                      <input placeholder="Your Name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <input placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <textarea placeholder="Describe your problem...." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <h6 class="text-center">Copyright &copy; Soni Computer Repairs</h6>
                <p class="text-center">www.SoniRepairs.com</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to use [Bootstrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to help your cause.  I set up a **[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hL5bLvmj/)**, where I put your HTML elements and CSS.  I restructured your elements into the grid system.  It then appears to do what you are wanting.  You can resize the **Result** window to see it perform in action.

```
<div class="container mainInfo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="contactInfo">
                CONTENT INFO GOES HERE
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="form">  
                    FORM GOES HERE
               </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- / col -->
    </div><!-- / row -->
</div><!-- / container -->
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        FOOTER CONTENT GOES HERE
    </div>
</footer>
```

Hope this helps.